# vext and vreinterpretq query

Tags: c, arm, simd, neon, cortex-a8

I want to implement below scalar logic:

```
    uint8_t s0[16] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
    uint8_t s1[16] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17};
    uint32_t width = 6 ;      //Varying between 5 to 9
    int32_t m1 = 32,m2 = 6;   //Dummy value

    for(int i =0,i<width;i++){
        uint32_t a1 =  s0[i] * m1;
        uint32_t a2 =  s1[i] * m2;
        uint32_t Result[i] = a1 + a2 ;  
    }
```

Neon:

```
uint8_t zeros[16] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
uint8x16_t v0_8x16 = vld1q_u8(&s0[0]);
uint8x16_t v1_8x16 = vld1q_u8(&s0[1]);
uint8x16_t vzero_8x16 = vld1q_u8(&zeros[0]);
int32x4_t axay1_6 = vdupq_n_s32(m1);
int32x4_t axay2_6 = vdupq_n_s32(m2);
```

I want to extract create new vector by extracting the v0_8x16  :

```
uint8x16_t v0_extract_8x16 = vext_s8(v0_8x16,vzero_8x16,width);
//Expectation:v0_extract_8x16  = {1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
//but with vext instruction I am getting,
//Reality: v0_extract_8x16  = {7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

and if I rechange also like `vext_s8(vzero_8x16,v0_8x16,width)` results are not like expected.

Can any one tell me:

- How can I get the expected v0_extract_8x16 by using neon intrinscics ?
- How can I convert 8x16 into 32x4 vector ?

Comment: `vext` is for extracting a full vector from the middle of two concatenated vectors, which isn't what you're looking to do. You could possibly try something like `vbit` to conditionally select elements of the data and a zero vector, but then you've got to faff around generating a mask vector from the width. Frankly, trying to process less than a full vector's worth of data is not a good fit for NEON code - with all the extra juggling you have to do to make it work, it's very likely to end up worse than the simple scalar loop.

Comment: @Notlikethat,Thanks for your reply .I want to try to do some neonization for above logic .i agree what you are telling but the I am feeling that if I will get 0.1 milisec of benefits also then its good .as above logic is in a big for loop which is going till 10k times .

Comment: @Notlikethat,Can you tell me how I can convert uint8_t to int32_t